# All directories containing lyx file re gone

Tags: files, restore, lyx

I got a weird problem.
I was editing a lyx document, and I tried to save a file. On my way saving the file I deleted a folder "PlayOnLinux" which I installed yesterday and it didnt work so i uninstalled it. The file system froze and then it said it ran into a problem and it closed. Then, all folder containing any .lyx file were gone, even the files that were not .lyx are gone. I don't know what happend.
Moreover, LyX doesnt work with hebrew anymore (it worked perfectly up until now).
Is there anyway I can restore the files? or restore the computer to a previous configuration or something?

thanks for any help

Comment: I decided this is not worth my time and reinstalled ubuntu.